# How to make 2 tag feeds show up on 1 page?

Tags: categories, pages, tags

I'm looking to create a page within my site that looks like this:

**Tag/Category: News**
News Post a
News Post b
News Post c

**Tag/Category: Events**
Event a
Event b
Event c

I'm new to Wordpress. I may not have the wordpress jargon to ask this correctly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to create a page template with the following code. Also you will need to decide if you will use a tag or category. The code below assumes you are using a category.

```
<div class="news">
<?php
  //The Query
  wp_query('showposts=5&category_name=News');

  //The Loop
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  ?> 
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <div class="post_content">
         <?php the_excerpt(); ?>    
    </div>
  <?
  endwhile; 
  endif;

  //Reset Query
  wp_reset_query();

  ?>
</div>

<div class="events">
  <?php 
    //The Query
    wp_query('showposts=5&category_name=Events');

    //The Loop
    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    ?> 
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <div class="post_content">
             <?php the_excerpt(); ?>    
        </div>
    <?
    endwhile; 
    endif;

    //Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();
  ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `query_posts()` should never be used for creating secondary loops [When should you use wp_query vs query_posts?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts).

Comment: Good point! I've updated to use wp_query

Comment: Ehm, it doesn't quite work like that. :) WP_Query is a class, it doesn't work like a drop-in replacement for a function. Please see question linked above for brief explanation and links to documentation.

Comment: Good point - I'll refactor and post it here... didn't even think of that :)